PDFKIT width property conflict issue with coordinates x and y
I'm using pdfkit to generate a pdf and am having troubles to print a text in an specific position and setting its width:
i've set doc as:
const doc = new PDFDocument({ size: 'A4', bufferPages: true, margins: { bottom: 0, }, })
Than i tried to print a text:
const longText = "... string that will for sure take more than a single line ..." const posX = doc.page.width/4 const posY = 10 doc.text(longText, posX, posY, {width: (doc.page.width/2)})
The problem is that the text is set in the right x,y position but goes beyond the page limit and never brecks.
If i use the code without posX and posY i get a text that breaks once it reaches the width but does not start in the right position?
I heard about setting the position before setting the options but it also does not work:
doc.text(null, posX, posY) doc.text(longText, {width: (doc.page.width/2)})
ps: sorry for bad english, not my first language
